# How to make a message in chat so when the owner joins it messages the server?

Tags: chat, roblox

I don't know how to make a message appear when the owner joins the server I tried searching on everything but I can not find an answer or a script.

Comment: Perhaps take a look at the docs for the [Lua Chat System](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/Lua-Chat-System). That might be a good starting point.

Comment: Ok I will try thank you

Comment: I tried but I don't think it works

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to post a message into chat. Replace the text with the message you want to display, then use a [RemoteEvent](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/RemoteEvent) to make this run on all clients when the owner joins.

```
local StarterGui = game:GetService("StarterGui")
StarterGui:SetCore("ChatMakeSystemMessage", {
    Text = "The owner has joined";
    Color = Color3.fromRGB(255, 255, 255);
    Font = Enum.Font.SourceSansBold;
    TextSize = 18
})
```